# Why is an async method with await keyword still blocking the main thread?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Can anyone explain to me the difference between these 2 async methods?

Method A

```
public async Task<List<Thumbnail>> GetAllThumbnailsAsync()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>             
    {
        var imageUris = GetAllDirectoriesWithImageAsync(CommandBaseUri).Result;

        return imageUris.Select(GetThumbnail).OrderByDescending(t => t.ImageDateTime).ToList();
    });
}
```

Method B

```
public async Task<List<Thumbnail>> GetAllThumbnailsAsync()
{
    var imageUris = await GetAllDirectoriesWithImageAsync(CommandBaseUri);

    return imageUris.Select(GetThumbnail).OrderByDescending(t => t.ImageDateTime).ToList();           
}
```

To my understanding both methods should return to the caller and does not block the UI thread, but in this case only Method A works as expected while Method B blocks my UI.

I believe there must be some fundamental concept that I may have misunderstood in the usage of async/await.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Can you show how are you calling those methods?

Comment: You might want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682513/task-factory-startnew-vs-async-methods)

Comment: `MethodB` will block for as long as `GetAllDirectoriesWithImageAsync` blocks. Without seeing it, we can't tell you whether that is likely to be a long time or not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: It won't be blocking the UI thread during that time. It's the second part of the async method that's the problem here, IMO.

Comment: Hard to believe you could have *that* many image files.  At least tell us how many.

Comment: @JonSkeet - if that method in fact spends a great deal of its time acting synchronously before ever starting a task or in other ways "going async" we may be paying for all of the I/O costs inside that method before it returns. I don't see how your crystal ball can tell you its cheap/not the issue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Ah yes, I see what you mean - I'd consider the method to be broken in that case. I read your comment as meaning "as long as it takes to get all the directories". I'd suggest it's at least *more likely* that `GetAllDirectoriesWithImageAsync` is okay, but that it's fetching the thumbnails that's broken. (I've edited my answer to mention that though.)

Comment: @HansPassant Only around 60 images.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, my `GetAllDirectoriesWithImageAsync` is not complex, in fact it's first call is an awaitable method.

Comment: StartNew is dangerous exactly in such cases: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: @VMAtm Thanks for the link, I really didn't know those complications existed, I just sort of followed the bandwagon since `Task.Factory` came into existence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method A is basically executing *everything* in a separate task, which will probably end up in a new thread. When you await the resulting task, you won't block anything.

Method B starts by calling `GetAllDirectoriesWithImageAsync`, and awaits the result. That means while the asynchronous operation is processing, you won't be blocking the UI thread - but by default, when you await the task, that means the continuation will run in the UI thread. So the `imageUris.Select(...).OrderByDescending(...).ToList()` will run in the UI thread, and I suspect *that's* the part that's causing problems in the UI.

Now you *could* call `.ConfigureAwait(false)` at the end of the first line of `GetAllThumbnailsAsync`, to indicate that you don't *need* to execute the second part on the UI thread - but that wouldn't guarantee that you *wouldn't* execute the second part on the UI thread. Instead, it seems to me that you really want an asynchonous way of getting thumbnails. Then you could do something like:

```
public async Task<List<Thumbnail>> GetAllThumbnailsAsync()
{
    var imageUris = await GetAllDirectoriesWithImageAsync(CommandBaseUri)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    var thumbnailTasks = imageUris.Select(GetThumbnailAsync).ToList();
    var thumbnails = await Task.WhenAll(thumbnailTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // I'm assuming there will be sufficiently few thumbnails here
    // that sorting them on the UI thread wouldn't be a problem, in
    // the unlikely event that we're *really* still on the UI thread by
    // this point...
    return thumbnails.OrderByDescending(t => t.ImageDateTime).ToList();           
}
```

Note that I'm assuming that all async methods are written reasonably, e.g. that `GetAllDirectoriesWithImageAsync` doesn't perform a significant amount of synchronous work before returning a task.

Comment: It was the second part of the method that was causing the problems. I confirmed by wrapping only the second part in `Task.Factory.StartNew`. It takes around 2-3 seconds which is weird, as the `GetThumbnail` is just a object mapping method. However, I'm still confused as to which part is ran on the UI thread though, isn't the second part of the code of Method B supposed to be like a callback for the first 'await'?

Comment: @IvanJazz: Yes, and that will be scheduled on the UI thread by default, if you called the whole method from the UI thread. (Not sure what you mean by "just a object mapping method" - if it's talking to the database, you may be making N queries. We don't really have enough information to say at the moment.)